# Interpolation using ratios in overall data

Tags: r, data.table

Here is the how the `data.table` `z` looks. (`dput` output provided at the bottom of the question)-

```
> require(data.table); z
     SurveyResponseID WhereStayed        LoS   Nights
  1:          3274455  Wellington 42741.9436   0.0000
  2:          3274476      Raglan 39591.9555   0.0000
  3:          3274493    Auckland   877.0862 877.0862
  4:          3274503    Matakohe  6865.8103       NA
  5:          3274506    Auckland 81982.5017   0.0000
 ---                                                 
146:          3275696    Clevedon  2871.3504       NA
147:          3275707    Hastings   748.8108 561.6081
148:          3275708   Stratford 23785.4769   0.0000
149:          3275715     Waitomo  1600.3829   0.0000
150:          3275728 Cape Reinga 11787.2847   0.0000
```

The column `Nights` has a few `NA`s. I'd like to apportion the value of `LoS` in the same ratio that the places of `WhereStayed` occurs in the rest of the non-`NA` data.

For example, consider the cases where `SurveyResponseID == 3274528`.

```
> z[SurveyResponseID == 3274528]
   SurveyResponseID WhereStayed      LoS Nights
1:          3274528    Auckland 20113.82     NA
2:          3274528    Hamilton 20113.82     NA
3:          3274528     Rotorua 20113.82     NA
```

Now, in the complete data, this is the distribution of Auckland, Rotorua and Hamilton -

```
> z[WhereStayed %in% c('Rotorua', 'Hamilton', 'Auckland') & !is.na(Nights), .(Nights = sum(Nights)), by = WhereStayed]
   WhereStayed   Nights
1:    Auckland 5019.240
2:    Hamilton 1502.824
3:     Rotorua 3271.130
```

Which is approximately `51.25%` Auckland, `15.35%` Hamilton and `33.4%` Rotorua. Using these shares, I'd like to distribute `20113.82` in that ratio and assign it back to the three `NA` s for the respondent `3274528`.

So, the data after the `NA` imputation would look like, since `5397.309 = 26.8% * 20113.82`-

```
> z[SurveyResponseID == 3274528]
   SurveyResponseID WhereStayed      LoS    Nights
1:          3274528    Auckland 20113.82 10308.802
2:          3274528    Hamilton 20113.82  3086.585
3:          3274528     Rotorua 20113.82  6718.435
```

I do have a solution which involves an intermediate data.table and then a join back to the `z` `data.table`, but I'm not sure that's the most `data.table` way to do things.

The following is my long approach which works, but is clunky.

```
ratios <- z[!is.na(Nights), .(Ratio = sum(Nights)), by = .(WhereStayed)]
ratios[, Ratio:=Ratio/sum(Ratio)]
z <- ratios[z, on = 'WhereStayed']
z[, Ratio:=Ratio/sum(Ratio), by = .(SurveyResponseID)]
z[is.na(Nights), Nights:=LoS*Ratio]
```

This has the following expected output (only shown for `is.na(Nights)`)-

```
    SurveyResponseID    WhereStayed        LoS    Nights
 1:          3274503       Matakohe  6865.8103        NA
 2:          3274528       Auckland 20113.8224 10308.802
 3:          3274528       Hamilton 20113.8224  3086.585
 4:          3274528        Rotorua 20113.8224  6718.435
 5:          3274583       Auckland 11712.8500 11712.850
 6:          3274607  Rakino Island  1161.6147        NA
 7:          3274715      Port Levy  2312.9432        NA
 8:          3274738 Waiheke Island  3036.9614        NA
 9:          3274752       Auckland   718.4200   718.420
10:          3274752          Kumeu   718.4200     0.000
11:          3274899       Auckland 96724.3395 96724.339
12:          3275082          Orewa  2125.8577        NA
13:          3275238       Auckland  4904.1634  4904.163
14:          3275256          Kumeu  5607.1564       NaN
15:          3275309       Auckland  4319.0176  4319.018
16:          3275319       Auckland  8634.8011  8634.801
17:          3275525       Auckland 25661.6887 25661.689
18:          3275560 Waiheke Island   915.7693        NA
19:          3275560       Auckland   915.7693        NA
20:          3275696       Clevedon  2871.3504  2871.350
```

The missings that are still present in `Nights` are okay because there was no data to draw from, in `z` for those cases.

#### The data for this question -------------------------

```
z <- structure(list(SurveyResponseID = c(3274455L, 3274476L, 3274493L, 
3274503L, 3274506L, 3274510L, 3274517L, 3274518L, 3274523L, 3274526L, 
3274528L, 3274528L, 3274528L, 3274532L, 3274583L, 3274594L, 3274605L, 
3274607L, 3274629L, 3274645L, 3274655L, 3274659L, 3274679L, 3274679L, 
3274692L, 3274694L, 3274700L, 3274709L, 3274715L, 3274719L, 3274726L, 
3274738L, 3274750L, 3274752L, 3274752L, 3274764L, 3274771L, 3274771L, 
3274789L, 3274800L, 3274838L, 3274839L, 3274843L, 3274866L, 3274866L, 
3274874L, 3274880L, 3274880L, 3274894L, 3274899L, 3274912L, 3274918L, 
3274923L, 3274947L, 3274966L, 3274971L, 3274979L, 3274980L, 3275003L, 
3275019L, 3275046L, 3275050L, 3275052L, 3275057L, 3275064L, 3275072L, 
3275075L, 3275079L, 3275082L, 3275085L, 3275101L, 3275102L, 3275103L, 
3275108L, 3275128L, 3275129L, 3275150L, 3275152L, 3275160L, 3275166L, 
3275170L, 3275170L, 3275174L, 3275174L, 3275210L, 3275230L, 3275238L, 
3275240L, 3275246L, 3275256L, 3275280L, 3275288L, 3275292L, 3275294L, 
3275295L, 3275304L, 3275309L, 3275319L, 3275330L, 3275344L, 3275362L, 
3275378L, 3275379L, 3275394L, 3275399L, 3275406L, 3275409L, 3275411L, 
3275411L, 3275418L, 3275436L, 3275443L, 3275454L, 3275463L, 3275465L, 
3275470L, 3275496L, 3275498L, 3275504L, 3275510L, 3275521L, 3275525L, 
3275538L, 3275544L, 3275545L, 3275546L, 3275554L, 3275555L, 3275555L, 
3275556L, 3275556L, 3275556L, 3275560L, 3275560L, 3275563L, 3275566L, 
3275569L, 3275581L, 3275604L, 3275606L, 3275626L, 3275638L, 3275683L, 
3275691L, 3275692L, 3275696L, 3275707L, 3275708L, 3275715L, 3275728L
), WhereStayed = c("Wellington", "Raglan", "Auckland", "Matakohe", 
"Auckland", "Christchurch", "Auckland", "Milton", "Dannevirke", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Hamilton", "Rotorua", "Twizel", "Auckland", 
"Otaki", "Greymouth", "Rakino Island", "Houhora", "Napier", "Christchurch", 
"Waipoua Forest", "Oamaru", "Dunedin", "Wellington", "Hamilton", 
"Westport", "Wellington", "Port Levy", "Lake Tekapo", "Milton", 
"Waiheke Island", "Paihia", "Auckland", "Kumeu", "Omarama", "Rotorua", 
"Tauranga", "Timaru", "Abel Tasman National Park", "Auckland", 
"Queenstown", "Warkworth", "Te Anau", "Craigieburn", "Milford Sound", 
"Nelson", "Christchurch", "Rotorua", "Auckland", "New Plymouth", 
"Christchurch", "Queenstown", "Kumeu", "Auckland", "Paparoa National Park", 
"Waiotapu", "Whangarei", "Waitomo", "Queenstown", "Auckland", 
"Queenstown", "Christchurch", "Clevedon", "Waitomo", "Christchurch", 
"Taihape", "Christchurch", "Orewa", "Rotorua", "Franz Josef", 
"Pukekohe", "Kumeu", "Tairua", "Taupo", "Queenstown", "Omarama", 
"Auckland", "Hanmer Springs", "Rotorua", "Murchison", "Queenstown", 
"Queenstown", "Milford Sound", "Auckland", "Paparoa National Park", 
"Auckland", "Cromwell", "Queenstown", "Kumeu", "Clevedon", "Wellington", 
"Oamaru", "Queenstown", "Endeavour Inlet", "Blenheim", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Wellington", "Wanaka", "Masterton", "Whakapapa Village", 
"Tairua", "Rotorua", "Cape Kidnappers", "Waihua", "Arrowtown", 
"Cape Reinga", "Snells Beach", "Auckland", "Wellington", "Dunedin", 
"Auckland", "Taupo", "Abel Tasman National Park", "Dunedin", 
"Te Anau", "Christchurch", "Paihia", "Dunedin", "Hamilton", "Auckland", 
"Matamata", "Wanaka", "Catlins", "Paihia", "Franz Josef", "Taupo", 
"Kaikoura", "Westport", "Heaphy Track", "Piha", "Waiheke Island", 
"Auckland", "Wellington", "Whangamata", "Wanaka", "Westport", 
"Fiordland National Park", "Taupo", "Christchurch", "Te Anau", 
"Wellington", "Rotorua", "Marlborough", "Clevedon", "Hastings", 
"Stratford", "Waitomo", "Cape Reinga"), LoS = c(42741.9436047755, 
39591.9555163287, 877.08616280446, 6865.81028982635, 81982.5016525796, 
41375.3053535933, 4949.00343037598, 13643.8378966971, 1818.04165680688, 
7911.06178019024, 20113.8223823246, 20113.8223823246, 20113.8223823246, 
4297.21264743424, 11712.8500000521, 14342.9323259751, 1046.42962365774, 
1161.61465947518, 26684.8013647668, 2159.85594913809, 12382.5291370991, 
3572.88522911463, 3267.58643173956, 3267.58643173956, 9055.02741317069, 
42964.024708285, 62527.1602217821, 799.215837399333, 2312.9432017275, 
17807.880584828, 3684.55279910826, 3036.96143529467, 2095.19366998327, 
718.419976697589, 718.419976697589, 1299.69196347729, 56914.2840041613, 
56914.2840041613, 13328.4852202518, 5404.91247034716, 2522.48422126056, 
6165.64136973517, 9531.97012687062, 3894.39120716227, 3894.39120716227, 
2543.46846269262, 3414.14874750348, 3414.14874750348, 3771.30561388102, 
96724.3394654342, 3583.27705777555, 3041.13854297752, 3368.50460565427, 
3158.18811352136, 3904.66470252172, 5862.90633463616, 2882.83911001206, 
11805.2297665087, 6402.08709024943, 5186.94312706125, 870.69199642505, 
10091.1420543283, 8369.774757932, 7985.40888579288, 6926.3302645866, 
4420.06917925033, 1726.86768006798, 3974.48164722869, 2125.85771144444, 
4736.76735216895, 14504.7530311797, 62467.3075924298, 632.428436718402, 
6645.29389114695, 2241.80914051178, 1003.1560691685, 3134.88061131533, 
3604.1357395957, 48790.3266929933, 2098.82030322716, 3945.49519922237, 
3945.49519922237, 2136.34311305016, 2136.34311305016, 456.440663951212, 
10692.5752772267, 4904.16336515106, 10440.7991489425, 8828.17020986572, 
5607.15637428966, 4374.48421791468, 23277.4964101353, 3380.0999904256, 
1255.85228651154, 12561.9210632003, 7779.33569261148, 4319.01757077778, 
8634.80105492512, 12844.081196906, 3666.71285119098, 4176.94496342972, 
3288.20886332444, 2937.47178044397, 10205.4005090231, 19213.3721518298, 
8527.86375947078, 10195.2603554514, 3735.66582375512, 3735.66582375512, 
946.998025480878, 5279.64787567089, 10608.0756829274, 6242.27906140245, 
5455.41709954626, 1779.0727991838, 6029.46747996311, 4385.52398444791, 
14686.4890994835, 4171.39583798557, 2475.27432897754, 3005.64728199526, 
25661.6887253572, 11185.9596078473, 3539.88530105119, 13857.1961646826, 
3799.52953818341, 4053.93637885706, 3771.87058713216, 3771.87058713216, 
26410.8270985288, 26410.8270985288, 26410.8270985288, 915.769260388995, 
915.769260388995, 3294.46869510517, 4859.6269254318, 1968.91705023579, 
547.139652678248, 4224.21312757923, 11692.2356812747, 712.516366875341, 
9217.08214243521, 1265.12928478973, 5665.77537103692, 14824.4623882922, 
2871.35038838803, 748.810764275115, 23785.4768813912, 1600.38293737054, 
11787.2847424015), Nights = c(0, 0, 877.08616280446, NA, 0, 40170.1993724207, 
0, 2842.46622847856, 303.006942801147, 1483.32408378567, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 74.7449731184097, NA, 0, 479.967988697354, 
0, 0, 136.149434655815, 136.149434655815, 0, 0, 0, 72.6559852181211, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 99.9763048828681, 503.666230125321, 
503.666230125321, 416.515163132868, 0, 360.354888751508, 362.68478645501, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 512.122312125522, 1877.78181112691, 179.585981613382, 
NA, 275.636696751966, 0, 748.556579034282, 0, 433.851633613524, 
279.186015935055, 0, 380.813863435765, 0, 357.720215659397, 870.69199642505, 
630.696378395519, 697.481229827667, 0, 0, 1262.87690835724, 90.8877726351567, 
722.633026768853, NA, 338.340525154925, 0, 54548.916489164, 0, 
4651.70572380286, 104.270192581943, 154.331702949, 174.160033961963, 
300.344644966308, 0, 0, 219.194177734576, 219.194177734576, 0, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 8828.17020986572, NA, 4374.48421791468, 705.37867909501, 
160.957142401219, 179.407469501649, 0, 0, NA, NA, 856.272079793735, 
0, 219.839208601564, 102.756526978889, 267.04288913127, 833.093919103928, 
0, 275.092379337767, 0, 0, 81.2101266033722, 0, 310.567522098288, 
1811.13487269492, 693.58656237805, 363.694473303084, 0, 415.825343445732, 
230.817051813048, 0, 641.753205843934, 190.405717613657, 1502.82364099763, 
NA, 0, 307.816113134886, 6928.59808234131, 0, 0, 377.187058713216, 
377.187058713216, 614.205281361134, 1228.41056272227, 0, NA, 
NA, 3294.46869510517, 0, 0, 39.081403762732, 0, 6820.47081407691, 
712.516366875341, 801.485403690018, 0, 1416.44384275923, 658.864995035208, 
NA, 561.608073206336, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(integer(0), "`__SurveyResponseID`" = integer(0)))
```

Comment: @akrun. I have added a working approach with the expected output. David Arenburg's approach works well, and produces the same outcome with fewer lines of code; if you have an even better approach, please let me know!

Comment: you might also want to check out treatment of censored data in statistics...as replicating from other survey responses might skew your analysis.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for the nudge. That does seem relevant. In this particular case, I think replicating would be fine as I have to interpolate only for about `1.2%` of the cases. But I'll read up on treatment of censored data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a reference data with the sums by `WhereStayed` and then run a join while calculating the new values, e.g.

```
## reference table with the sums
ref <- z[!is.na(Nights), .(Nights = sum(Nights)), by = WhereStayed]

## join z with ref
z[is.na(Nights), # join only where `Nights` are NAs
  Nights := ref[.SD, Nights / sum(Nights) * LoS, # Calculate the formula per join
                on = .(WhereStayed)], # join condition
  by = SurveyResponseID] # run this by `SurveyResponseID`

## Validation
z[SurveyResponseID == 3274528]
#    SurveyResponseID WhereStayed      LoS    Nights
# 1:          3274528    Auckland 20113.82 10308.802
# 2:          3274528    Hamilton 20113.82  3086.585
# 3:          3274528     Rotorua 20113.82  6718.435
```